# How to solve Error importing: pycurl lib. To install it on Debian based systems: $ 'sudo apt-get install python3-pycurl'

Tags: python, github, libs

can someone help me i get this error when i try starting ufonet

https://github.com/epsylon/ufonet

```
I get this: Error importing: pycurl lib.
```

To install it on Debian based systems:

```
 $ 'sudo apt-get install python3-pycurl'
```

Im on Windows 10 and using Cmd Thanks for helping XD

Comment: It doesn't look like it works on Windows at all.

Comment: But why i get the Lib errror?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not a git question so I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Windows can't run UfoNet with CMD.
You may try it on such as Linux or the other OS.
sudo apt-get command is used only for Linux or Kali Linux things.